# How to make users not to delete suffix in EditText?

Tags: android, input, filter, android-edittext, cursor

i create a form with an EditText that takes in input numberDecimal (i set `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` in related XML file) and i write the following activity that prevent inserting numbers with more than 2 decimal places (i used `.setFilters()`). In addition i set a suffix in the same EditText and i would avoid that users can delete this suffix, neither add some input after it. I mean that if users go at the end of the EditText and tries to press backspace button the cursor goes at the begin of the suffix " m" (including space).
How to do that?

```
public class InputForm extends Activity {
    EditText inputField;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input_form);    

        inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInput);
        inputField.setText(" m");
        inputField.setSelection(0);

        inputField.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2)});
}

    public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {
        Pattern mPattern;
        public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsAfterZero) {
            mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            int input_length = dest.length() - 2; // lenght of the input without " m"

            Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(dest.subSequence(0, input_length));

            if(!matcher.matches())
                return "";

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can manage keeping the right side of your `EditText` would be to arrange the layout such that it is composed of 2 `EditText` views.  One with a layout attribute to the right and another with a layout to the left of the suffix `EditText` filling up the remainder of the layout window.

Then make the second `EditText` unselectable.  If you don't put borders around the `EditText` and force the text in the window on the left to type from right to left, then you will get the appearance you desire.

You could also keep track of the cursor and then after input you could change the position of the cursor if it is in the wrong location, or check the input for having the suffix that you are expecting and replace it as they type.  This will have very little visually noticeable change.  But I don't believe there is a built-in way to handle the approach you are requesting.

Comment: The truth is that i reached my purpose yesterday. Today i add check on 2 decimal positions, and now i cannot remember again how i did it :(